# How to compute correlation when deviations on a variable are known

Tags: correlation, standard-deviation, pearson-r, spearman-rho

I have two vectors $X$ and $Y$. $Y$ is a binary vector (i.e. takes values between $0$ and $1$). I have a standard deviation vector $d_X$ corresponding to $X$, i.e. $d_X(i)$ is the standard deviation of $X(i)$. No such deviation vector exists for $Y$.

Is it possible to compute correlation between $X$ and $Y$ using measures such as Pearson, Spearman, Kendall's tau etc. ?

Comment: Sorry.. _Standard_ deviation $\sigma$ is a sample statistic. Do you rather mean just deviation of a point from the mean or such deviation divided by $\sigma$ (and known as _z-score_)?

Comment: @ttnphns Yes, deviation of a point from the mean. In this case, $X$ contains means of various measurements and $d_X$ contains corresponding standard deviations.